# Will the Airy pattern be preserved for high numerical aperture lens?

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction, photonics

All we know that a lens focuses a plane wave into an Airy pattern distribution. However, what if the numerical aperture ($NA$) will be very high, like more than $0.99$ (in the air) or with focusing angles up to $90^\circ$? My concern is that with higher angles we have more waves, propagating almost parallel to the focusing plane, consequently contributing to the total focusing pattern as just interference bands. So, the Airy pattern will be overlapped with these interference bands and will be spoiled. Is my understanding correct or the Airy pattern still be preserved even for $NA$ up to $1$ (in the air)?

Comment: When you talk about near and far-field, are you concerned about evanescent waves? Or are you concerned about the scalar description, which I used? I agree that I did not address these topics that's why I deleted my answer. Furthermore, you said that you used a "Fourier propagator". Could you please specify your transfer fit. Probably the good approach would be to use Huygen's superposition principle and to calc the resulting field amplitude.

Comment: Yeah, my concern is evanescent fields! So, I used the angular spectrum method: introduce hyperbolic phase profile, make FFT, then propagate the field (transfer function is without approximations $exp(-iz\sqrt(1/\lambda^2-k_{x}^2-k_{y}^2))$) and finally inverse FFT. Why do you think Huygens's intergrals would be better? I know that FFT should be faster.